# TextField.getText() causes errors in actionPerformed

Tags: java, swing

I am making a program, where one part of the program is to obtain inputted text from the user, which is in the text field. And check if the inputted text is equal to "Bless you". And if that is true, one boolean variable gets reset, and I call repaint to trigger other paint functions. I am using 'String input = TextField.getText()' but every time I type something into the text field and hit enter, there is a whole bunch of errors. Can someone tell me if I am using getText() wrong? Thank you.

Here is my code-

```
// 3/22/19
// SneezePanels.java
/*  IDEA of this program:  PanelHolder, which is added to the frame, holds two panels,
LeftPanel and RightPanel, which are added to PanelHolder in a GridLayout. The 
LeftHolder has a BorderLayout and has two panels-a direction panel, with a FlowLayout 
that has a the button, and a textField panel that contains the textField.  When
the button is pressed, Achoo and a yellow oval are drawn on the Right Panel.  
When the user types in "Bless you" in the textField, the RightPanel is erased
and variables are reset.
*/
/// Testing:  Only clicking on the button will draw on the right panel.  Only typing 
/// in "Bless you" will clear it.
/// Try clicking anywhere other that the button.  This should will not change anything.  
/// Typing anything other than "Bless you" will not reset the panels.

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;   
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;  
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.Color;      
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Font;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class SneezePanels
{   
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SneezePanels sp = new SneezePanels();
        sp.run();
    }

    public SneezePanels()
    {   
    }

    public void run()
    {
        JFrame sneezeFrame = new JFrame ("Sneeze and Bless you.");

        sneezeFrame.setSize( 600, 400);             
        sneezeFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        sneezeFrame.setLocation(400,50);
        sneezeFrame.setResizable(true);
        PanelHolder pHolder = new PanelHolder(); 
        sneezeFrame.add( pHolder );     
        sneezeFrame.setVisible(true);   
    }

// This panel holds two panels-one on the left and one on the right, aptly named
class PanelHolder extends JPanel
{
    private RightPanel rp;  // these are field variables so the nested classes have access to them
    private boolean nosePressed;    // otherwise, we have to use getter-setter methods
    private Font font;

    private JTextArea directions;
    private JButton nose;
    private JTextField blessYou;


    public PanelHolder()
    {
        setLayout( new GridLayout(1, 2) );
        nosePressed = false;
        font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20);

        LeftPanel lp = new LeftPanel();
        add(lp);
        rp = new RightPanel();
        add( rp );
    }

    // This panel will have a BorderLayout
    //  It will have the directions panel in the center, and the 
    // textField panel in the south. 
    class LeftPanel extends JPanel 
    {   
        public LeftPanel()
        {   
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            // setBackground( Color.MAGENTA );

            DirectionPanel dirP = new DirectionPanel ();
            TFPanel tfp = new TFPanel();

            add ( dirP, BorderLayout.CENTER );
            add ( tfp, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

        }

    }

    // DirectionPanel will print the directions and contain the 
    // nose button.  It has a FlowLayout.  It will use a 
    // ButtonHandler for actionPerformed.
    class DirectionPanel extends JPanel
    {

        public DirectionPanel()
        {

            setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            nose = new JButton("nose");

            Button1Handler b1 = new Button1Handler();

            nose.addActionListener(b1);

            add(nose);

            directions = new JTextArea("Directions: Press button to tickle the nose.");
            add(directions);

            setBackground(Color.RED);
        }   

        public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);

        }

    }

    // The TFPanel will have a FlowLayout and contain a text field
    // that will be on the left.  It uses a handler class for 
    // actionPerformed
    class TFPanel extends JPanel
    {
        private JTextField blessYou;

        public TFPanel()
        {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            blessYou = new JTextField();


            TextFieldHandler tfh = new TextFieldHandler();
            blessYou.addActionListener(tfh);
            blessYou.setText("Type: Bless you");
            add(blessYou);
        }
    }

    // The RightPanel is used to draw "Achoo" and a yellow oval when the
    // button is pressed and cleared when "Bless you" is typed in
    // the textField
    class RightPanel extends JPanel
    {

        public RightPanel()
        {

        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            if(nosePressed)
            {
                g.setFont(font);
                g.drawString("Achoo!", 125, 60);
                g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g.fillOval(100, 80,100, 120);

            }

        }

    }

    // When the button is pressed, the method actionPerformed is 
    // used to call paintComponent in RightPanel
    class Button1Handler implements ActionListener 
    {
        public Button1Handler()
        {
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {

            if(e.getSource() == nose)
            {
                nosePressed = true;

            }

            rp.repaint();
        }
    }   // end class Button1Handler 

    // When the user types in "Bless you" in the textField, the 
    // boolean is reset and RightPanel's paintComponent is called
    class TextFieldHandler implements ActionListener 
    {
        public TextFieldHandler()
        {


        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {   
            ****String input = blessYou.getText(); ****

            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("bless you"))
            {
                nosePressed = false;
                rp.repaint();

            }

        }
    }   // end class TextFieldHandler
}
}
```

I have put 4 asterisks on the line that is causing errors based on the compiler. The line is in the class 'TextFieldHandler' (bottom of code- last class) and is in the actionPerformed method. The main error is `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SneezePanels$PanelHolder$TextFieldHandler.actionPerformed(SneezePanels.java:211)` (line 211 is the line I put 4 asterisks on, it is in the class TextFieldHandler). There also a bunch of other errors referring to the JPanel and JFrame classes.

What I want it to do is to take the inputted text from the TextField, which is called 'blessYou' and then check if the inputted string is equal to 'Bless you' and then if it is, reset the boolean variable nosePressed to false, and then repaint. All help is appreciated. Please ask me if you have any questions about my code.

Comment: `blessYou` you defined twice, once in `PanelHolder` (which is never initialised) and once in `TFPanel`.  `TextFieldHandler` can only see the instance declared in `PanelHolder` (which is `null`).  "A" possible solution would be to pass a reference of `blessYou` to `TextFieldHandler`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh, I see. I have removed the the JTextField declared in ```PanelHolder```. And what do you mean by passing a reference of blessYou to TextFieldHandler? I have made an instance of TextFieldHandler and added that as the ActionListener. Is that what you mean?

Comment: convert blessYou.getText();  into blessYou.getText().toString();

Comment: @AsadAli Why? `JTextField#getText()` returns a `String`

Comment: @PrasanthDendukuri I mean, you should make `TextFieldHandler` so it requires a `JTextField` to be passed to it, then it doesn't care, it will use the reference passed to it. See [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer its character array not string

Comment: @AsadAli [I beg your pardon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText--)?  You might be thinking of `JPasswordField`, but even then `getText` will return a `String`.  Besides `[char].toString` would be really bad idea as that wouldn't convert the character array to a `String` of the characters, but would provide a debug view of the array ...

Comment: @MadProgrammer lets see if this help's in solving the error

Comment: @AsadAli Since `blessYou` is `null` it won't help any more then your other suggestions, apart from miss leading the OP

Comment: @MadProgrammer i think there is a confusion i am getting this as an android textview

Comment: @AsadAli Ahh, `import javax.swing.JTextField;` is not an Android component ;) - there's not a single piece of Android code in the posted example

Comment: @AsadAli Also, for reference, `System.out.println(new char[] {'t', 'e', 's', 't'}.toString());` prints `[C@4d591d15`, not `test`

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes this is what i said its confusion because i think this is an android question

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you, all I had to do was remove one of the empty references of blessYou which I declared twice and it got fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the second declaration of blessYou as shown below. It is hiding 'the other' one.

```
class TFPanel extends JPanel
{
    // private JTextField blessYou;

    public TFPanel()
    {
```